# How to assign response object to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I could get data from nodejs backend to react frontend using axios. But I can't assign that object to state object in React.

```
getData=()=>{
  let responseToHandle;
  axios.get("http://localhost:9000/api/getData")
    .then(function (response) 
     {
      console.log(response.data);//This is working
      responseToHandle = response.data;
      console.log(responseToHandle);//This is working
      this.setState({
        data: responseToHandle}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.data)
        })
      })



// HERE IS MY STATE OBJECT


state={
  data:[]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `console.log()`?

Comment: Because you are logging after the promise, meaning that bottom log executes first and then asynchronous one once request is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axios` call and `this.setState` are both asynchronous.

You must add your desired code inside a callback:

```
this.setState({
    data: responseToHandle
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    // Now you can use this.state.data
});
```

**Edit:**

You also need to change

`axios.get("http://localhost:9000/api/getData").then(function (response) { ... })`

to

`axios.get("http://localhost:9000/api/getData").then(response => { ... })`

Without arrow function the scope inside `.then()` is the `function` scope, different from `component` scope, which means using `this` gives you a different value.

Comment: Edit your question to add what you have tried which is giving the same problem.

Comment: Change `axios.get("http://localhost:9000/api/getData").then(function (response) { ... })` to `axios.get("http://localhost:9000/api/getData").then(response => { ... })` Without arrow function the scope inside `.then()` is different from component scope, which means using `this` gives you a different value.

Answer (score 1):

This code won't work properly:

```
console.log(this.state.data)
```

You called a `console.log` function synchronously right after a promise declaration. Promise works asynchronously.

So in order to check a new state, you should call `console.log` in `render()` method, or the best option is to use `componentDidUpdate()` method.

E.g.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log(`Previous data: ${prevState.data}`);
  console.log(`New data: ${this.state.data}`);
}
```